# Git Security Issues

Tags: git, security

Using version control in an Enterprise system presents a plethora of issues. One of which is security, with files transferring back and forth between desktops and servers. In trying to select a DVCS system, Git is a player worth looking at but there are not any clear descriptions of how secure it is in that Enterprise system.

What security issues are prevalent in using Git in an Enterprise system?

Comment: What security issues are you talking about? Are you asking how to do simple file ACLs, or git authentication?

Comment: No programing involved, try at superuser with a little more effort in describing your concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A git repository is simply speaking just a bunch of files. The important question is how you access those files. Git makes it very easy for you for you to utilize SSH or HTTPS for data transfer, but it does not offer you such service directly.

Your options are not limited to SSH and HTTPS, but those two are secure(1) *if configured and used correctly*.

Choose any SSH server (e.g. openSSH) or any HTTP server (e.g. apache) that you are familiar with and you know how to configure for a secure setup. (configuration includes ensuring good cipher algorithms are used, certificates are used correctly and users have strong passwords or even better authenticate using a key file. Additionally you need users to have write access. In case of apache this means that you need to enable mod_dav).

Then on the client just checkout your repository using `git clone ssh://user@server/path/to/project.git` (in the case of ssh) or `git clone https://example.com/path/to/project.git` in the case of https.

(1) security experts know that security is always relative and you can always make a system even more secure, but unless you have extremely special high security otherwise-the-nuclear-power-plant-blows-up requirement, you can assume that ssh and https are secure (anyway security is most often enough not about the your transport protocols anymore but about how to stop people from posting their passwords on facebook and their [credit card number on twitter](https://twitter.com/NeedADebitCard)).

Comment: I installed Git and a Git GUI yesterday to start 'actually' working with it. I didn't see any settings/preferences files, where would you configure SSH/FTP/etc for your transfers?

Comment: @randomblink: I expanded my answer to be more precise.